# Unknown TI microcontroller identification

Tags: microcontroller, identification, texas-instruments

80-pin QFP package, has JTAG, UART, connected LCD. Powered by 3V Li battery.
Package marking: **80AGL 10A2K**.
[image: 80AGL 10A2K 80AGL10A2K]
Can't find anything similar on TI's site and google.

Comment: You mention it has JTAG. What does that identify the part as?

Answer (score 1):

Probably an ASIC, meaning you are stuck. TI has a large division specialising in them.